# Proper use of update_user_meta

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm having difficulties understanding how to properly use the `update_user_meta`. Right now I have two functions that should update the user meta_key. However, the `theme_levels` functions overrides the ajax function each time probably because of the `wp_head` filter. Is there a better way?

My code is as follows

```
function theme_levels() {

    $value = user_total_posts( get_current_user_id() )

    if( $value >= '0' && $value <= '499' ) {        
        $levels[] = array(
                'level'         => 'level-1',               
        );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'author_level', $levels );         
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_levels' );
```

Then I have an ajax callback, which should add another array to the same user meta_key.

```
function ajax_callback() {  
    if( ! empty( $_POST['data-id'] ) ) {        
        $levels[] = array(
                'notification'  => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['data-id'] ),
        );      
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'author_level', $levels);        
    }

    wp_die();   
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_theme_ajax', 'ajax_callback' );
```

This is how I want it to be ( it's also partly a `var_dump` on `$levels` ):

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["level"]           => string(10) "level-1" // this will be added if user is logged in and reached the level
        ["notification"]    => string(28) "level-1-notification-read" // this should be added after the AJAX call
    } 
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `$user_id` you are using is not defined anywhere.

Please use below code within function `theme_levels()` and `ajax_callback()` in the beginning.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id=$current_user->ID;
```

Comment: Hi Rafin, in my php file `$user_id` is defined as `get_current_user_id()`, however somehow in my post here, I forgot to add it. Thanks for pointing that out. That being said, my issue still remains. How to stop the `theme_levels()` function from overridding the AJAX function?